# How to color System.out.println output?

Tags: java, colors, system.out

How can I color Java output?

For example in C and other languages I can use ANSI-escape like `\033[0m` to do this. But in Java it doesn't work.

```
public static void main(String[] x) {
    System.out.println("\033[0m BLABLA \033[0m\n");
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No, but there are third party API's that can handle it

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2002-12/02-qa-1220-console.html

Edit: of course there are newer articles than that one I posted, the information is still viable though.

Above link is dead, see this question instead: [How to print color in console using System.out.println?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762491/how-to-print-color-in-console-using-system-out-println)

Comment: This post has a good answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5762502/70535

Comment: The link is broken now

Answer (score 131):

#### Note

You may not be able to color Window's `cmd prompt`, but it should work in many unix (or unix-like) terminals.

Also, note that some terminals simply won't support some (if any) ANSI escape sequences and, especially, 24-bit colors.

#### Usage

Please refer to the section **Curses** at the bottom for the best solution. For a personal or easy solution (although ***not*** as cross-platform solution), refer to the **ANSI Escape Sequences** section.

---

## TL;DR

- **java**: `System.out.println((char)27 + "[31m" + "ERROR MESSAGE IN RED");`
- **python**: `print(chr(27) + "[31m" + "ERROR MESSAGE IN RED")`
- **bash** or **zsh**: `printf '\x1b[31mERROR MESSAGE IN RED'`

  - this may also work for Os X: `printf '\e[31mERROR MESSAGE IN RED'`
- **sh**: `printf '`<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>,<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>`[31mERROR MESSAGE IN RED'`

  - ie, press *CTRL+V* and then *CTRL+[* in order to get a "raw" <kbd>ESC</kbd> character when escape interpretation is not available
  - If done correctly, you should see a `^[`. Although it looks like two characters, it is really just one, the <kbd>ESC</kbd> character.
  - You can also press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>,<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> in **vim** in any of the programming or sripting langauges because that uses a literal <kbd>ESC</kbd> character
  - Also, you can replace <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> with <kbd>ESC</kbd> … eg, you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>,<kbd>ESC</kbd>, but I find the former easier, since I am already pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and since <kbd>[</kbd> is less out of the way.

---

## ANSI Escape Sequences

### Background on Escape Sequences

While it is not the best way to do it, the easiest way to do this in a programming or scripting language is to use *[escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence)*. From that link:

> An escape sequence is a series of characters used to change the state of computers and their attached peripheral devices. These are also known as control sequences, reflecting their use in device control.

### Backgound on ANSI Escape Sequences

However, it gets even easier than that in video text terminals, as these terminals use *[ANSI escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)*. From that link:

> ANSI escape sequences are a standard for in-band signaling to control the cursor location, color, and other options on video text terminals. Certain sequences of bytes, most starting with Esc and '[', are embedded into the text, which the terminal looks for and interprets as commands, not as character codes.

### How to Use ANSI Escape Sequences

#### Generally

- Escape sequences begin with an escape character; for ANSI escape sequences, the sequence always begins with <kbd>ESC</kbd> (ASCII: `27` / hex: `0x1B`).
- For a list of what you can do, refer to the [ANSI Escape Sequence List on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Escape_sequences)

#### In Programming Languages

Some programming langauges (like Java) will not interpret `\e` or `\x1b` as the <kbd>ESC</kbd> character. However, we know that the ASCII character `27` **is** the <kbd>ESC</kbd> character, so we can simply typecast `27` to a `char` and use that to begin the escape sequence.

Here are some ways to do it in common programming languages:

- **Java**

  - `System.out.println((char)27 + "[33mYELLOW");`
- **Python 3**

  - `print(chr(27) + "[34mBLUE");`
  - `print("\x1b[35mMAGENTA");`

    - Note that `\x1b` is interpretted correctly in python
- **Node JS**

  - The following will **NOT** color output in JavaScript in the Web Console
  - `console.log(String.fromCharCode(27) + "[36mCYAN");`
  - `console.log("\x1b[30;47mBLACK_ON_WHITE");`

    - Note that `\x1b` also works in node

#### In Shell Prompt OR Scripts

If you are working with *bash* or *zsh*, it is quite easy to color the output (in most terminals). In Linux, Os X, and in some Window's terminals, you can check to see if your terminal supports color by doing both of the following:

- `printf '\e[31mRED'`
- `printf '\x1b[31mRED'`

If you see color for both, then that's great! If you see color for only one, then use that sequence. If you do not see color for either of them, then double check to make sure you typed everything correctly and that you are in bash or zsh; if you still do not see any color, then your terminal probably does not support ANSI escape sequences.

If I recall correctly, linux terminals tend to support both `\e` and `\x1b` escape sequences, while os x terminals only tend to support `\e`, but I may be wrong. Nonetheless, if you see something like the following image, then you're all set! (Note that I am using the shell, *zsh*, and it is coloring my prompt string; also, I am using *urxvt* as my terminal in linux.)

[image: ANSI Escape Sequences Coloring Text Red]

*"How does this work?"* you might ask. Bascially, `printf` is interpretting the sequence of characters that follows (everything inside of the *single-quotes*). When `printf` encounters `\e` or `\x1b`, it will convert these characters to the <kbd>ESC</kbd> character (ASCII: 27). That's just what we want. Now, `printf` sends <kbd>ESC</kbd>`31m`, and since there is an <kbd>ESC</kbd> followed by a valid ANSI escape sequence, we should get colored output (so long as it is supported by the terminal).

You can also use `echo -e '\e[32mGREEN'` (for example), to color output. Note that the `-e` flag for `echo` *"[enables] interpretation of backslash escapes"* and must be used if you want `echo` to appropriately interpret the escape sequence.

---

## More on ANSI Escape Sequences

ANSI escape sequences can do more than just color output, but let's start with that, and see exactly how color works; then, we will see how to manipulate the cursor; finally, we'll take a look and see how to use 8-bit color and also 24-bit color (although it only has tenuous support).

On [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), they refer to <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> as `CSI`, so I will do the same.

### Color

To color output using ANSI escapes, use the following:

- `CSI` `n` `m`

  - `CSI`: escape character—`^[[` or <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>
  - `n`: a number—one of the following:

    - `30`-`37`, `39`: foreground
    - `40`-`47`, `49`: background
  - `m`: a literal ASCII `m`—terminates the escape sequence

I will use bash or zsh to demonstrate all of the possible color combinations. Plop the following in bash or zsh to see for yourself  (You may need to replace `\e` with `\x1b`):

- `for fg in {30..37} 39; do for bg in {40..47} 49; do printf "\e[${fg};${bg}m~TEST~"; done; printf "\n"; done;`

Result:

[image: various foreground/background colors using ANSI escapes]

#### Quick Reference (Color)

```
+~~~~~~+~~~~~~+~~~~~~~~~~~+
|  fg  |  bg  |  color    |
+~~~~~~+~~~~~~+~~~~~~~~~~~+
|  30  |  40  |  black    |
|  31  |  41  |  red      |
|  32  |  42  |  green    |
|  33  |  43  |  yellow   |
|  34  |  44  |  blue     |
|  35  |  45  |  magenta  |
|  36  |  46  |  cyan     |
|  37  |  47  |  white    |
|  39  |  49  |  default  |
+~~~~~~+~~~~~~+~~~~~~~~~~~+
```

### Select Graphic Rendition (SGR)

SGR just allows you to change the text. Many of these do not work in certain terminals, so use these sparingly in production-level projects. However, they can be useful for making program output more readable or helping you distinguish between different types of output.

Color actually falls under SGR, so the syntax is the same:

- `CSI` `n` `m`

  - `CSI`: escape character—`^[[` or <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>
  - `n`: a number—one of the following:

    - `0`: reset
    - `1`-`9`: turns on various text effects
    - `21`-`29`: turns off various text effects (less supported than `1`-`9`)
    - `30`-`37`, `39`: foreground color
    - `40`-`47`, `49`: background color
    - `38`: 8- or 24-bit foreground color (see **8/24-bit Color** below)
    - `48`: 8- or 24-bit background color (see **8/24-bit Color** below)
  - `m`: a literal ASCII `m`—terminates the escape sequence

Although there is only tenuous support for faint (2), italic (3), underline (4), blinking (5,6), reverse video (7), conceal (8), and crossed out (9), some (but rarely all) tend to work on linux and os x terminals.

It's also worthwhile to note that you can separate any of the above attributes with a semi-colon. For example `printf '\e[34;47;1;3mCRAZY TEXT\n'` will show `CRAZY TEXT` with a `blue foreground` on a `white background`, and it will be `bold` and `italic`.

Eg:

[image: string attributes together example screenshot]

Plop the following in your bash or zsh shell to see all of the text effects you can do. (You may need to replace `\e` with `\x1b`.)

- `for i in {1..9}; do printf "\e[${i}m~TEST~\e[0m "; done`

Result:

[image: SGR state 1]
[image: SGR state 2]

You can see that my terminal supports all of the text effects **except** for *faint* (2), *conceal* (8) and *cross out* (9).

#### Quick Reference (SGR Attributes 0-9)

```
+~~~~~+~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~+
|  n  |  effect          |
+~~~~~+~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~+
|  0  |  reset           |
|  1  |  bold            |
|  2  |  faint*          |
|  3  |  italic**        |
|  4  |  underline       |
|  5  |  slow blink      |
|  6  |  rapid blink*    |
|  7  |  inverse         |
|  8  |  conceal*        |
|  9  |  strikethrough*  |
+~~~~~+~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~+

* not widely supported
** not widely supported and sometimes treated as inverse
```

### 8-bit Color

While most terminals support this, it is less supported than `0-7`,`9` colors.

Syntax:

- `CSI` `38;5;` `n` `m`

  - `CSI`: escape character—`^[[` or <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>
  - `38;5;`: literal string that denotes use of 8-bit colors for foreground
  - `n`: a number—one of the following:

    - `0`-`255`

If you want to preview all of the colors in your terminal in a nice way, I have [a nice script on gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/dylnmc/93e9d0e923adccc73487431066125853).

It looks like this:

[image: 8-bit color example screenshot]

If you want to change the background using 8-bit colors, just replace the `38` with a `48`:

- `CSI` `48;5;` `n` `m`

  - `CSI`: escape character—`^[[` or <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>
  - `48;5;`: literal string that denotes use of 8-bit colors for background
  - `n`: a number—one of the following:

    - `0`-`255`

### 24-bit Color

Also known as true color, 24-bit color provides some really cool functionality. Support for this is definitely growing (as far as I know it works in most modern terminals except *urxvt*, my terminal [insert angry emoji]).

24-bit color is actually supported in vim (see the [vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_GUI_color_settings_in_a_terminal) to see how to enable 24-bit colors). It's really neat because it pulls from the colorscheme defined for gvim; eg, it uses the fg/bg from `highlight guibg=#______ guifg=#______` for the 24-bit colors! Neato, huh?

Here is how 24-bit color works:

- `CSI` `38;2;` `r` `;` `g` `;` `b` `m`

  - `CSI`: escape character—`^[[` or <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>
  - `38;2;`: literal string that denotes use of 24-bit colors for foreground
  - `r`,`g`,`b`: numbers—each should be `0`-`255`

To test *just a few* of the many colors you can have (`(2^8)^3` or `2^24` or `16777216` possibilites, I think), you can use this in bash or zsh:

- `for r in 0 127 255; do for g in 0 127 255; do for b in 0 127 255; do printf "\e[38;2;${r};${g};${b}m($r,$g,$b)\e[0m "; done; printf "\n"; done; done;`

Result (this is in *gnome-terminal* since ***urxvt* DOES NOT SUPPORT 24-bit color** ... get it together, urxvt maintainer ... for real):

[image: 24-bit color example screenshot]

If you want 24-bit colors for the background ... you guessed it! You just replace `38` with `48`:

- `CSI` `48;2;` `r` `;` `g` `;` `b` `m`

  - `CSI`: escape character—`^[[` or <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>
  - `48;2;`: literal string that denotes use of 24-bit colors for background
  - `r`,`g`,`b`: numbers—each should be `0`-`255`

### Inserting Raw Escape Sequences

Sometimes `\e` and `\x1b` will not work. For example, in the *sh* shell, sometimes neither works (although it does on my system **now**, I don't think it used to).

To circumvent this, you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>,<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>,<kbd>ESC</kbd>

This will insert a "raw" <kbd>ESC</kbd> character (ASCII: 27). It will look like this `^[`, but do not fret; it is only one character—not two.

Eg:

[image: sh raw escape char example screenshot]

---

## Curses

Refer to the [Curses (Programming Library) page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29) for a full reference on curses. It should be noted that curses only works on unix and unix-like operating systems.

### Up and Running with Curses

I won't go into too much detail, for search engines can reveal links to websites that can explain this much better than I can, but I'll discuss it briefly here and give an example.

#### Why Use Curses Over ANSI Escapes?

If you read the above text, you might recall that `\e` or `\x1b` will sometimes work with `printf`. Well, sometimes `\e` and `\x1b` will not work at all (this is not standard and I have never worked with a terminal like this, but it is possible). More importantly, more complex escape sequences (think <kbd>Home</kbd> and other multi-character keys) are difficult to support for every terminal (unless you are willing to spend a lot of time and effort parsing terminfo and termcap and and figuring out how to handle every terminal).

Curses solves this problem. Basically, it is able to understand what capabilities a terminal has, using these methods (as described by the wikipedia article linked above):

> Most implementations of curses use a database that can describe the capabilities of thousands of different terminals. There are a few implementations, such as PDCurses, which use specialized device drivers rather than a terminal database. Most implementations use terminfo; some use termcap. Curses has the advantage of back-portability to character-cell terminals and simplicity. For an application that does not require bit-mapped graphics or multiple fonts, an interface implementation using curses will usually be much simpler and faster than one using an X toolkit.

Most of the time, curses will poll terminfo and will then be able to understand how to manipulate the cursor and text attributes. Then, you, the programmer, use the API provided by curses to manipulate the cursor or change the text color or other attributes if the functionality you seek is desired.

#### Example with Python

I find python is really easy to use, but if you want to use curses in a different programming language, then simply search it on duckduckgo or any other search engine. :) Here is a quick example in python 3:

```py
import curses

def main(stdscr):
    # allow curses to use default foreground/background (39/49)
    curses.use_default_colors()

    # Clear screen
    stdscr.clear()

    curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_RED, -1)
    curses.init_pair(2, curses.COLOR_GREEN, -1)
    stdscr.addstr("ERROR: I like tacos, but I don't have any.\n", curses.color_pair(1))
    stdscr.addstr("SUCCESS: I found some tacos.\n", curses.color_pair(2))

    stdscr.refresh() # make sure screen is refreshed
    stdscr.getkey()  # wait for user to press key

if __name__ == '__main__':
    curses.wrapper(main)
```

result:

[image]

You might think to yourself that this is a much more round-about way of doing things, but it really is much more cross-platform (really cross-terminal … at least in the unix- and unix-like-platform world). For colors, it is not *quite* as important, but when it comes to supporting other multi-sequence escape sequences (such as <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>Page Up</kbd>, <kbd>Page Down</kbd>, etc), then curses becomes all the more important.

#### Example with Tput

- `tput` is a command line utility for manipulating cursor and text
- `tput` comes with the `curses` package. If you want to use cross-terminal (ish) applications in the terminal, you should use tput, as it parses terminfo or whatever it needs to and uses a set of standardized commands (like curses) and returns the correct escape sequence.
- example:

```sh
echo "$(tput setaf 1)$(tput bold)ERROR:$(tput sgr0)$(tput setaf 1) My tacos have gone missing"
echo "$(tput setaf 2)$(tput bold)SUCCESS:$(tput sgr0)$(tput setaf 2) Oh good\! I found my tacos\!"
```

Result:

[image: example with tput]

#### More Info on Tput

- see: http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_adv_tput.php to see how tput works
- see: http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html for a list of commands that you can use

Comment: `(char) 27` can also be represented by the char (it can be represented as a String, too since it a String is a sequence of chars and the escape `"\"` and what follows it until the `"m"` gets treated as a single char) `"\u001b"` or (as I noticed on [ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=341144)) by the char `"\003"`.

Comment: it works on Win7 in Idea14

Answer (score 32):

This has worked for me:

```
System.out.println((char)27 + "[31mThis text would show up red" + (char)27 + "[0m");
```

You need the ending "[37m" to return the color to white (or whatever you were using).  If you don't it may make everything that follows "red".

Comment: Cool! How do you do another color this way?

Comment: Refer to this question for other ANSI codes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762491/how-to-print-color-in-console-using-system-out-println

Comment: doesn't work for me... i try inside eclipse, and calling jar file from cmd

Answer (score 14):

Yes it is 100% possible

set classpath= %classpath%;d:\jansi-1.4.jar;

Try this below code:

```
import org.fusesource.jansi.AnsiConsole;
import static org.fusesource.jansi.Ansi.*;
import static org.fusesource.jansi.Ansi.Color.*;

public class Sample

{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    AnsiConsole.systemInstall();

    System.out.println(ansi().fg(RED).a("Hello World").reset());
    System.out.println("My Name is Raman");

    AnsiConsole.systemUninstall();
  }
}
```

Comment: great - this is the easiest, most straightforward and visually understandable solution that works universally!

Answer (score 12):

You can use the [JANSI](http://jansi.fusesource.org/) library to render ANSI escape sequences in Windows.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution for Win32 Console.

1) Get JavaNativeAccess libraries here: https://github.com/twall/jna/

2) These two Java classes will do the trick.

Enjoy.

```
package com.stackoverflow.util;

import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Platform;
import com.sun.jna.Structure;

public class Win32 {
    public static final int STD_INPUT_HANDLE = -10;
    public static final int STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11;
    public static final int STD_ERROR_HANDLE = -12;

    public static final short CONSOLE_FOREGROUND_COLOR_BLACK        = 0x00;
    public static final short CONSOLE_FOREGROUND_COLOR_BLUE         = 0x01;
    public static final short CONSOLE_FOREGROUND_COLOR_GREEN        = 0x02;
    public static final short CONSOLE_FOREGROUND_COLOR_AQUA         = 0x03;
    public static final short CONSOLE_FOREGROUND_COLOR_RED          = 0x04;
    public static final short CONSOLE_FOREGROUND_COLOR_PURPLE       = 0x05;
    public static final short CONSOLE_FOREGROUND_COLOR_YELLOW       = 0x06;
    public static final short CONSOLE_FOREGROUND_COLOR_WHITE        = 0x07;
    public static final short CONSOLE_FOREGROUND_COLOR_GRAY         = 0x08;
    public static final short CONSOLE_FOREGROUND_COLOR_LIGHT_BLUE   = 0x09;
    public static final short CONSOLE_FOREGROUND_COLOR_LIGHT_GREEN  = 0x0A;
    public static final short CONSOLE_FOREGROUND_COLOR_LIGHT_AQUA   = 0x0B;
    public static final short CONSOLE_FOREGROUND_COLOR_LIGHT_RED    = 0x0C;
    public static final short CONSOLE_FOREGROUND_COLOR_LIGHT_PURPLE = 0x0D;
    public static final short CONSOLE_FOREGROUND_COLOR_LIGHT_YELLOW = 0x0E;
    public static final short CONSOLE_FOREGROUND_COLOR_BRIGHT_WHITE = 0x0F;

    public static final short CONSOLE_BACKGROUND_COLOR_BLACK        = 0x00;
    public static final short CONSOLE_BACKGROUND_COLOR_BLUE         = 0x10;
    public static final short CONSOLE_BACKGROUND_COLOR_GREEN        = 0x20;
    public static final short CONSOLE_BACKGROUND_COLOR_AQUA         = 0x30;
    public static final short CONSOLE_BACKGROUND_COLOR_RED          = 0x40;
    public static final short CONSOLE_BACKGROUND_COLOR_PURPLE       = 0x50;
    public static final short CONSOLE_BACKGROUND_COLOR_YELLOW       = 0x60;
    public static final short CONSOLE_BACKGROUND_COLOR_WHITE        = 0x70;
    public static final short CONSOLE_BACKGROUND_COLOR_GRAY         = 0x80;
    public static final short CONSOLE_BACKGROUND_COLOR_LIGHT_BLUE   = 0x90;
    public static final short CONSOLE_BACKGROUND_COLOR_LIGHT_GREEN  = 0xA0;
    public static final short CONSOLE_BACKGROUND_COLOR_LIGHT_AQUA   = 0xB0;
    public static final short CONSOLE_BACKGROUND_COLOR_LIGHT_RED    = 0xC0;
    public static final short CONSOLE_BACKGROUND_COLOR_LIGHT_PURPLE = 0xD0;
    public static final short CONSOLE_BACKGROUND_COLOR_LIGHT_YELLOW = 0xE0;
    public static final short CONSOLE_BACKGROUND_COLOR_BRIGHT_WHITE = 0xF0;

    // typedef struct _COORD {
    //    SHORT X;
    //    SHORT Y;
    //  } COORD, *PCOORD;
    public static class COORD extends Structure {
        public short X;
        public short Y;
    }

    // typedef struct _SMALL_RECT {
    //    SHORT Left;
    //    SHORT Top;
    //    SHORT Right;
    //    SHORT Bottom;
    //  } SMALL_RECT;
    public static class SMALL_RECT extends Structure {
        public short Left;
        public short Top;
        public short Right;
        public short Bottom;
    }

    // typedef struct _CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO {
    //    COORD      dwSize;
    //    COORD      dwCursorPosition;
    //    WORD       wAttributes;
    //    SMALL_RECT srWindow;
    //    COORD      dwMaximumWindowSize;
    //  } CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO;
    public static class CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO extends Structure {
        public COORD dwSize;
        public COORD dwCursorPosition;
        public short wAttributes;
        public SMALL_RECT srWindow;
        public COORD dwMaximumWindowSize;
    }

    // Source: https://github.com/twall/jna/nonav/javadoc/index.html
    public interface Kernel32 extends Library {
        Kernel32 DLL = (Kernel32) Native.loadLibrary("kernel32", Kernel32.class);

        // HANDLE WINAPI GetStdHandle(
        //        __in  DWORD nStdHandle
        //      );
        public int GetStdHandle(
                int nStdHandle);

        // BOOL WINAPI SetConsoleTextAttribute(
        //        __in  HANDLE hConsoleOutput,
        //        __in  WORD wAttributes
        //      );
        public boolean SetConsoleTextAttribute(
                int in_hConsoleOutput, 
                short in_wAttributes);

        // BOOL WINAPI GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(
        //        __in   HANDLE hConsoleOutput,
        //        __out  PCONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO lpConsoleScreenBufferInfo
        //      );
        public boolean GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(
                int in_hConsoleOutput,
                CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO out_lpConsoleScreenBufferInfo);

        // DWORD WINAPI GetLastError(void);
        public int GetLastError();
    }
}
```

```
package com.stackoverflow.util;

import java.io.PrintStream;

import com.stackoverflow.util.Win32.Kernel32;

public class ConsoleUtil {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    throws Exception {
        System.out.print("abc");
        static_color_print(
                System.out, 
                "def", 
                Win32.CONSOLE_BACKGROUND_COLOR_RED, 
                Win32.CONSOLE_FOREGROUND_COLOR_BRIGHT_WHITE);
        System.out.print("def");
        System.out.println();
    }

    private static Win32.CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO _static_console_screen_buffer_info = null; 

    public static void static_save_settings() {
        if (null == _static_console_screen_buffer_info) {
            _static_console_screen_buffer_info = new Win32.CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO();
        }
        int stdout_handle = Kernel32.DLL.GetStdHandle(Win32.STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        Kernel32.DLL.GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(stdout_handle, _static_console_screen_buffer_info);
    }

    public static void static_restore_color()
    throws Exception {
        if (null == _static_console_screen_buffer_info) {
            throw new Exception("Internal error: Must save settings before restore");
        }
        int stdout_handle = Kernel32.DLL.GetStdHandle(Win32.STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        Kernel32.DLL.SetConsoleTextAttribute(
                stdout_handle, 
                _static_console_screen_buffer_info.wAttributes);
    }

    public static void static_set_color(Short background_color, Short foreground_color) {
        int stdout_handle = Kernel32.DLL.GetStdHandle(Win32.STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        if (null == background_color || null == foreground_color) {
            Win32.CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO console_screen_buffer_info = 
                new Win32.CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO();
            Kernel32.DLL.GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(stdout_handle, console_screen_buffer_info);
            short current_bg_and_fg_color = console_screen_buffer_info.wAttributes;
            if (null == background_color) {
                short current_bg_color = (short) (current_bg_and_fg_color / 0x10);
                background_color = new Short(current_bg_color);
            }
            if (null == foreground_color) {
                short current_fg_color = (short) (current_bg_and_fg_color % 0x10);
                foreground_color = new Short(current_fg_color);
            }
        }
        short bg_and_fg_color = 
            (short) (background_color.shortValue() | foreground_color.shortValue());
        Kernel32.DLL.SetConsoleTextAttribute(stdout_handle, bg_and_fg_color);
    }

    public static<T> void static_color_print(
            PrintStream ostream, 
            T value, 
            Short background_color, 
            Short foreground_color)
    throws Exception {
        static_save_settings();
        try {
            static_set_color(background_color, foreground_color);
            ostream.print(value);
        }
        finally {
            static_restore_color();
        }
    }

    public static<T> void static_color_println(
            PrintStream ostream, 
            T value, 
            Short background_color, 
            Short foreground_color)
    throws Exception {
        static_save_settings();
        try {
            static_set_color(background_color, foreground_color);
            ostream.println(value);
        }
        finally {
            static_restore_color();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The simplest method is to run your program (unmodified) in Cygwin console.

The second simplest method is to run you program (also unmodified) in the ordinary Windows console, pipelining its output through tee.exe (from Cygwin or Git distribution). Tee.exe will recognize the escape codes and call appropriate WinAPI functions.

Something like:

```
java MyClass | tee.exe log.txt
java MyClass | tee.exe /dev/null
```

Answer (score 5):

I created a `jar` library called [JCDP](http://www.diogonunes.com/blog/java-colored-debug-printer/) (*Java Colored Debug Printer*).

For Linux it uses the ANSI escape codes that WhiteFang mentioned, but abstracts them using words instead of codes which is much more intuitive.

For Windows it actually includes the JAnsi library but creates an abstraction layer over it, maintaining the intuitive and simple interface created for Linux.

This library is licensed under the [MIT License](https://tldrlegal.com/license/mit-license) so feel free to use it.

Have a look at [JCDP's github repository](https://github.com/dialex/JCDP).

Answer (score 3):

Escape sequences must be interpreted by SOMETHING to be converted to color.  The standard CMD.EXE used by java when started from the command line, doesn't support this so therefore Java does not.

Comment: if you're running on a non-windows OS there's a good chance that the terminal app will do escape sequence interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

Check This Out: i used ANSI values with escape code and it probably not work in windows command prompt but in IDEs and Unix shell.
you can also check 'Jansi' library [here](https://github.com/fusesource/jansi)  for windows support.

```
System.out.println("\u001B[35m" + "This text is PURPLE!" + "\u001B[0m");
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a library called [AnsiScape](https://github.com/nomemory/ansiscape) that allows you to write coloured output in a more structured way:

Example:

```
AnsiScape ansiScape = new AnsiScape();
String colors = ansiScape.format("{red {blueBg Red text with blue background}} {b Bold text}");
System.out.println(colors);
```

The library it also allows you to define your own "escape classes" akin to css classes.

Example:

```
AnsiScapeContext context = new AnsiScapeContext();

// Defines a "class" for text
AnsiClass text = AnsiClass.withName("text").add(RED);
// Defines a "class" for the title used
AnsiClass title = AnsiClass.withName("title").add(BOLD, BLUE_BG, YELLOW);
// Defines a "class" to render urls
AnsiClass url = AnsiClass.withName("url").add(BLUE, UNDERLINE);

// Registering the classes to the context
context.add(text).add(title).add(url);

// Creating an AnsiScape instance with the custom context
AnsiScape ansiScape = new AnsiScape(context);

String fmt = "{title Chapter 1}\n" +
              "{text So it begins:}\n" +
              "- {text Option 1}\n" +
              "- {text Url: {url www.someurl.xyz}}";

System.out.println(ansiScape.format(fmt));
```

Answer (score -2):

System.err.println("Errorrrrrr") it will print text in Red color on console.

Answer (score -5):

This works in eclipse just to turn it red, don't know about other places.

```
System.err.println(" BLABLA ");
```

Comment: The op asked about System.out, not System.err. These two Streams might point to different locations.

Comment: Read the question `How to color System.out.println output?`

Comment: Its about printing fonts in different color. Error fonts are printed in Red by java itself. Your answer is not relatable to question.