# How to make a set choose a random name in a set

Tags: java, arrays, string, int, set

I have a lot of code here and I was wondering with this code how I could change it to make my set **randomly** choose one of the Strings in the set.
My code is here:

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<String> a = new HashSet<String>();
    Random as = new Random();
    ArrayList<String> suit = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("spades","diamonds","hearts","clubs"));
    a.add( "ace");
    a.add( "2");
    a.add( "3");
    a.add( "4");
    a.add( "5");
    a.add( "6");
    a.add( "7");
    a.add( "8");
    a.add( "9");
    a.add( "10");
    a.add( "Jack");
    a.add( "Queen");
    a.add( "King");
    System.out.println("" + a + " of " + suit.remove(sad.nextInt(suit.size())));
  }
}
```

I would really like to know as I have not figured it out yet, and it would help a lot in a card game I am making. Any dupes or websites are greatly appreciated.

Comment: [jansi](https://github.com/fusesource/jansi).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448858/how-to-color-system-out-println-output

Comment: If you're on a website, there are only really two possibilities. A) it cannot be done B) `System.out.println("<font color='red'><b>Like this</b></font>");`

Comment: I believe you cant change color with system.out.println because its an console output. You may try using label etc.

Comment: Can it be due to IDE settings?

Comment: maybe, can you check on the compiler, its in the question

Comment: @B.Polk Lower your expectations or stop relying on a free website to be your compiler and runtime.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch ok, Java Eclipse just won't download and finish.