# StringBuilder with some text in red overriding toString in Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I have been asked to Override the method toString of MyClass using StringBuilder and I have to append some text in red so it will look like that:

> Name: Tom
>
> Surname: Baker
>
> **Age: 17** --> Text in Red

Code:

```
@Override
public String toString(){

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder;
    sb.append("Name:"+this.name+"\n");
    sb.append("Surname:"+this.surname+"\n");
    sb.append("Age:"+this.age+"\n");

    return sb.toString();
}
```

### Edit

Thank you for your answers.

- The program is for a university assignment and it is being coded using Eclipse.
- It is basic Java (not RXJava)
- The output will be visualised through the console.
- The teacher ask that but I feel it is not possible.

Comment: `StringBuilder` and `String` do not have a color per se.  The color would have to come from somewhere else, e.g. HTML.  Can you add another tag to make your question clear?

Comment: Generally there is no such thing as "red text". Text is just a combination of bytes encoded on your screen to represent a sequence of characters. You need to specificy whether you are working with a Rich Text Format or other formats or we won't be able to help you here.

Comment: Could you specify what kind of program is it? It is a web application or desktop using Swing or JavaFX

Comment: Expanding on @TimBiegeleisen's comment, how to colorize the text (and whether that's possible at all) depends entirely on the output mechanism. If it's going to be printed on a terminal, ANSI escape codes are the way to go. If it's going to be rendered in a browser, use html (and make sure nothing is escaped). If it's Swing of JavaFX, html can also be used depending on how exactly the text is passed to the UI.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448858/how-to-color-system-out-println-output  Also check this please

Comment: Thank you very much. Does my edit help?

Comment: When using eclipse, text sent to `System.err` is normally printed in red. You might want to use the StringBuilder to compose name and surname and print the age to stderr.

Comment: stderr? How do I do that? and If I have to add another line after age?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since text printed on `System.err` is normally reported in red, you might try this:

```
public class MyClass
{
  .....

  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("Name: " + name);
    sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
    sb.append("Surname: " + surname);
    return (sb.toString());
  }

  public void printAge(PrintStream stream)
  {
    stream.println("Age: " + age);
  }

} // class MyClass

...
MyClass my_instance;
my_instance = new MyClass();
...
System.out.println(my_instance);
System.out.flush() // make sure everything's printed before doing something on stderr
my_instance.printAge(System.err);
System.err.flush() // make sure everything's printed before doing something on stdout again
System.out.println("Anything else to print");
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If the output is going to a colour terminal emulator, then you can insert the relevant control codes. There are mechanisms to determine terminal types, such as environment variables (`$TERM`) and telnet uses a negotiation system (`WILL`/`WONT`/`DO`/`DONT`, IIRC), but for your purposes you can probably just make the assumption.

Typically a baseline would be vt100 terminal emulation with "ANSI colors". Google for the codes. I get http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the info you need in the comments you have been given.

Look here if you want a simple wrapup:

On an ANSI terminal (Linux eg.), you could achieve that by inserting [ANSI Escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#3/4_bit)

```
System.out.println("Hello \033[31mWorld\033[0m!");
```

But that won’t work on a Windows console.

On a Windows console, you’ll have to use a third party library, like [JAnsi](https://github.com/fusesource/jansi)

```
import org.fusesource.jansi.Ansi;
import org.fusesource.jansi.AnsiConsole;

public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        AnsiConsole.systemInstall();
        System.out.println(Ansi.ansi().render("Hello @|red World|@!"));
        AnsiConsole.systemUninstall();
    }
}
```